What does it mean to say that egg derived vaccines are "cheap but slow to produce"?
A nature review of bird flu says:

currently available vaccines rely on inactivated strains of viruses grown in chicken eggs, which are cheap, but slow, to produce. Researchers are developing vaccines using mRNA technology...

A simple way to read this to mean something like "While egg based vaccines are cheap, the fact that they are slow means we should invest in developing vaccines using mRNA technology".
The timelime of egg based vaccine production is described here and summarised in the below graphic.  It takes about six months, but the first few are "Egg supply organisation", which could start now. and we can make billions of doses "cheaply".  We have a well established mechanism for selection and testing of the particular vaccine variant.  This timeline seems far preferable to anything involving developing vaccines using mRNA technology.
What does "cheap but slow" mean in this context?


Why would you think it is anything other than the reason you have in the last sentence?

This is a question and answer site about problems in biology. Your post, in contrast, is the expression of an opinion on methods of vaccine production, prefaced with a rhetorical question about the intent of an author in using a particular phrase. I therefore regard your question as it stands as off-topic.  You can make it on-topic by rewriting it addressing the question that concerns you directly: “Why is mRNA technology preferred to egg passage for producing vaccines for possible future pandemics?” or the like. Then it would be valid to suggest an argument.

@David My question is about the meaning of the particular phrase, used by the journal nature to justify a particular public health stance.  I added the details of egg based production because people thought my question was homework.  There is probably a reason for the use of the word "slow" when comparing these two technologies, whether that is related to the details of mRNA technology or egg based vaccines in this particular instance I do not know.

A question about the meaning of a phrase consisting of simple English words, and having no particular technical aspect is not an appropriate subject for questions on SE Biology. I am trying to help you present your concerns in an appropriate format, rather than just voting to close on these grounds, especially as you appear to understand quite well what the phrase means. It now seems that you wish to know how much slower propagation in eggs is than using mRNA and tissue culture. You might rephrase your question to make this your focus. But…

…first carefully re-read the article, which is not a review but a News item from one of Nature's correspondents. It does not attempt to "justify" anything, but reports the reasons given by various government organizations and associated scientists for decision they have made regarding vaccine development. As regards the advantages of mRNA technology given by one Scott Hensley, not only is speed cited, but the fact that "formulation can be updated to target emerging strains". Wishing to understand the reasons for such public health choices is fine, but trying to nit-pick a news article, is not.

In the context of a rapidly changing virus like Influenza (as that's what the article is talking about) the process is slow because no-one, including the experts, knows exactly which strains and variants are going to be around in the future.
The article notes that egg production takes some time to ramp up, but does NOT mention the work that is going on in the virology field of looking at the current strains of the viruses in the environment, both in humans and in birds and pigs. This work is carried out by a group known as the Global Influenza Surveillance and Response System (GISRS) at reference laboratories across the globe, including national influenza centres in each country, WHO collaborating laboratories, etc. In these laboratories the virologists determine the prevalence of strains of the virus that are present now, as well as which strains were present in the last year or more, and, critically, look at the immune patterns of the human population and how strongly viruses produce an immune response in people. These patterns are different in the Northern and Southern Hemispheres of the world. You can look at some of the information generated on FluNet.
This work involves screening millions of samples, determining the subtype (HA and N components), genome sequencing (now commonly done) or sequencing specific regions in the genome (previously), and then maybe looking at antigenicity of the virus itself if it is significantly different to ones not already looked at. This data is then shared globally through GISAID. The WHO teams will be discussing which viruses are looking like being present and developing stocks using GMP for distribution to the vaccine manufacturers.
With this information, the WHO vaccine team meets formally  to look at the virus and immune data and makes an informed decision on which viruses to include in the vaccine for the coming winter in each hemisphere. At this point, the exact virus component in each vaccine is released for the manufacturers to start growing it in the eggs (D0 in your graph), which actually takes about 6 months from the WHO vaccine decision meeting until release for the general population (note mid Feb to July/August in your figure), making it about a year in total (from D-6 to D0 to vaccine release at about D+6).
Egg production isn't as simple as mixing some virus with egg and taking the resulting mix to inject into people, it first needs to be purified (to remove egg components), made into subunits, tested to ensure that it has the right immunological response, etc. This all takes time. In addition, you need a LOT of eggs to make the amounts of virus needed for the vaccine. Some viruses don't grow as well as others, so you need to use more eggs. The eggs themselves also need to be the right age, with a chick of the right age (10-11 days post-fertilization) to produce a decent amount of virus; older or younger means less virus. Doing this sort of thing on an industrial scale is difficult!
In contrast, mRNA vaccines are in some manner simpler and more adaptable. First off, you are starting with pure substances for synthesis of the mRNA, this means that you don't need to go through a lot of the purification that an egg based vaccine does, and it can all be produced in a sterile environment, with much less of the messy biological side involved in eggs. In addition, these very pure inputs are often expensive to produce themselves, which adds to the cost compared to cheap eggs.
The adaptable bit means that you can change the mRNA relatively easily within the vaccine itself - say you had a variant with a specific mutation that gave a stronger immune response and you wanted to include that - simply plug that mutation into your pipeline and you have it shortly (in theory at least). Of course, you would still need to do the immune response testing etc, without the need to grow whole new viruses, generate stocks, distribute them, then grow new vaccine in bulk.
